# Problem with apt-get and locales (inappropriate # in .deb package name)

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, locale

First of all, I'm running Raspbian, any extra needed info, I will post it here, just ask for it.

EDIT:

Output of locales -a:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
POSIX
```

I configured `en_GB.utf8`, about the others, I don't know if they could be causing the problem...

I'm running into an issue with the pi,whenever I try to do anything with apt-get other than update, I get the following error message:

(after upgrade):

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10) ...
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
Success
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
dpkg-query: error: --status needs a valid package name but 'locales#' is not: illegal package name in specifier 'locales#': character `#' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')

Use --help for help about querying packages.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales# is not installed
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried lots of possible solutions I found online, including messing with /etc/environment (which was an empty file).

I have also tried following [these](https://www.linux-answered.com/2012/05/07/debian-locales-nightmares/) instructions, but nothing changed, probably because I couldn't solve the apt-get problem and because of that couldn't purge locales to install it again...

I don't know if this makes any sense, but I believe the problem comes from `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure:` pointing to `locales#` instead of `locales`, I just have no idea on where to change this...

Answer (score 1):

Found it, was actually the `/etc/default/locale`

It must have slipped me when editing it and I actually left no space between locale and the comment after it (#Comment here), hence it was getting the # from the comment... How silly...

If anyone ever gets anything like this, just look in your `/etc/default/locale`